# Is there a grid search functionality for general functions with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, python-multiprocessing, grid-search

I am trying to find the best parameters for a CNN model, with which I have the architecture stored in a function as follows:

```py
def MLmodel(parameters):
    #parameters = [kernel_count, learning_rate, regularization_parameters]
    return validation_accuracy
```

I am currently using tensorflow-gpu on my NVIDIA 1070 GPU for this model training. Is there a general grid searching function (much like GridSearchCV perhaps on sci-kit learn) that would be able to employ multiprocessing for finding the best parameter combination for the highest validation accuracy?

I tried using GridSearchCV and HalvingGridSearchCV, but I'm pretty sure those can only be used with SVM models, or some set of very specific ML model setups that my model is not a part of.

Comment: Check out Ray Tune (https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/examples/tune_mnist_keras.html)